# Why the size of malloc-ed array and non-malloced array are different?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int* arr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    int arr2[4];


    printf("%d \n", sizeof(arr1));
    printf("%d \n", sizeof(arr2));

    free(arr1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
8
16
```

Why?

Comment: First one: sizeof pointer. Second: sizeof array....

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: Ludin@ it's about heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Arrays are not pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/).***

In your code, `arr1` is a pointer, `arr2` is an array.

Type of `arr1` is `int *`, whereas, `arr2` is of type `int [4]`. So `sizeof` produces different results. Your code is equivalent to

```
sizeof (int *);
sizeof (int [4]);
```

That said, `sizeof` yields the result of type `size_t`, so you should be using `%zu` to print the result.

Comment: How to measure size of heap, what was malloc pointer on heap?

Comment: @JeungwooPark sadly, you cannot directly know the size of the allocated memory from the returned pointer, you have to keep track of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

arr1 is a pointer when you call sizeof(arr1) this will you size of pointer.
but arr2 represent block of memory for 4 integers.